# Delphi - BinToHex and HexToBin : Reversal

Tags: arrays, delphi, hex, byte, delphi-xe2

I have an array of byte that I wish to convert into a hex string, and then back into an array of byte.

I am using the following to convert into a hex string:

```
function bintoHex(const bin: array of byte): String;
const HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 2*Length(bin));
  for i :=  0 to Length(bin)-1 do begin
    Result[1 + 2*i + 0] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[i] shr 4];
    Result[1 + 2*i + 1] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[i] and $0F];
  end;
end;
```

I am unsure how to convert it back into an array of byte properly. I am shooting for something like the following:

```
Type TDCArray = Array of Byte;

function xHexToBin(const HexStr: String): TDCArray;
const HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, ???); //Need to now get half of the length, unsure how to go about that
  for i :=  0 to Length(HexStr)-1 do begin
    //Here convert back into an array somehow...
    //Result[i] := ???
  end;
end;
```

How would I go about doing this?

Also, I am using Delphi XE2.

Comment: RTL has a HexToBin and BinToHex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself:

```
function xHexToBin(const HexStr: String): TBytes;
const HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var i, J: integer;
    B: Byte;
begin
  SetLength(Result, (Length(HexStr) + 1) shr 1);
  B:= 0;
  i :=  0;
  while I < Length(HexStr) do begin
    J:= 0;
    while J < Length(HexSymbols) do begin
      if HexStr[I + 1] = HexSymbols[J + 1] then Break;
      Inc(J);
    end;
    if J = Length(HexSymbols) then ; // error
    if Odd(I) then
      Result[I shr 1]:= B shl 4 + J
    else
      B:= J;
    Inc(I);
  end;
  if Odd(I) then Result[I shr 1]:= B;
end;
```

Comment: Works perfect. I need the final result in Array of Byte rather than TBytes so I simply used: "For i := 0 to length(arrTBytes) do arrofByte[i] := arrTBytes[i];"  Thank you.

Comment: @JoshLine - `TBytes` is built-in RTL array of Byte type, you can use your `TDCArray` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just use the [`BinToHex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.BinToHex) and [`HexToBin`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) RTL functions?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  LArray : array[1..6] of Byte = (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
  LText: string;
  I : integer;
begin
  try
    SetLength(LText, Length(LArray)*2);
    BinToHex(@LArray, PChar(LText), SizeOf(LArray));
    //show the hex string
    Writeln(LText);

    //fill the array with 0 
    FillChar(LArray, SizeOf(LArray), #0);

    //get the values from the hex string
    HexToBin(PChar(LText), @LArray, Length(LArray));

    //show the array values
    for i := 1 to Length(LArray) do
      Write(LArray[i]);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Note those functions have a few quirks, such as lower-case alpha only. Read the docs carefully :)

Answer (score 4):

2 hex chars represent 1 byte

The code i wrote earlier was pseudocode I wanted you to get the ideea. But if you need some code to paste here is the actual implementation:

```
program project1;

uses SysUtils,classes;


type
  TByteArray = array of byte;
function StrToArray(const Hexstr: String): TByteArray ;
var
i: Integer;
begin
SetLength(Result, Length(Hexstr) div 2);
for i:=0 to (Length(Hexstr) div 2 - 1) do
        Result[i]:= StrToInt('$' + Copy(Hexstr, (i * 2) + 1, 2));
end;


var
   arr : TByteArray;
   i : Integer;
begin
  arr := StrToArray('0A0B0C0D');
  for i:=0 to High(arr) do
          WriteLn(arr[i]);
  Readln;
end.
```

Btw coding is not about cuting and pasting ;)

Comment: I get "Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'string'" on this Line:


    Result[i]:= '$' + Copy(Hexstr, (i * 2) + 1, 2);

Comment: sorry don't have a compiler try now

Comment: I cant set the function type to an array of byte...and when trying to run the function it simply crashed the application. :/

Comment: Funny thing is, I now know. I learned something. I am still in school learning computer science. I have just begun. Simply because I did not know the answer is sad? Then every post here is "sad"? I LEARNED from the responses, and now know and understand the answer, It's sad that you have to be rude for no reason. I did try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Forms, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, Classes;

type

  { TTextToHex_HexToBin }

  TTextToHex_HexToBin = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    CheckTime: TImage;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CheckTimeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  TextToHex_HexToBin: TTextToHex_HexToBin;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TTextToHex_HexToBin }

//hex to binary

function HextoBinary(const AHexStr: string):string;
var
  i, j: Integer;
const
  HexParts: array[0..$F] of string =
    (
    {0} '0000',{1} '0001',{2} '0010',{3} '0011',{4} '0100',{5} '0101',{6} '0110',{7} '0111',
    {8} '1000',{9} '1001',{A} '1010',{B} '1011',{C} '1100',{D} '1101',{E} '1110',{F} '1111'
     );

begin
SetLength(Result, 4 * AHexStr.Length);
  j := 1;
  for i := 1 to AHexStr.Length do
  begin
    case AHexStr[i] of
      '0'..'9':
        Move(HexParts[Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('0')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
      'A'..'F':
        Move(HexParts[$A + Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('A')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
      'a'..'f':
        Move(HexParts[$A + Ord(AHexStr[i]) - Ord('a')][1], Result[j], sizeof(char) * 4);
    else
      raise EConvertError.CreateFmt('Invalid hexadecimal string "%s".', [AHexStr]);
    end;
    Inc(j, 4);
  end;
end;

procedure TTextToHex_HexToBin.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  TB: TBytes;
  WS: WideString;
  S:  string;
  i:  Integer;

begin
  WS := Trim(Edit1.Caption);
  TB := WideBytesOf(WS);

  // WideString to Hexadecimal
  S := '';
  for i := Low(TB) to High(TB) do
    S := S + IntToHex(TB[i], -1);
  Edit2.Caption :=Trim(S);

  // Hex to Binary

    Memo1.Caption:= HextoBinary(Trim(S));
end;

procedure TTextToHex_HexToBin.CheckTimeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TTextToHex_HexToBin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

[Result Show as Below]